# How to get rid of blinking fields and cursor when hovering over this field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 2 sections of code, first for the desktop version, the second for the mobile version. The first version works correctly (the first image)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDMvF.png), an error appears in the mobile version, when you hover over the list item hover, the effect does not work, border color appears (background (second image))[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frYfl.png), if you move the cursor to this border, hover works, but the field itself starts blinking. If you enter in the code of the mobile version the dimensions of the list item, as in the version for large monitors, i.e. duplicate the rules, both the field and the cursor blink. How to solve this situation, so that instead of the appearance of a colored border, there is a hover effect without blinking? Below is the html and css of the problem place, and just for javascript.

```js
if ('ontouchstart' in window) { var click = 'touchstart'; }
else { var click = 'click'; }


$('div.burger').on('click', function () {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) { openMenu(); }
  else { closeMenu(); }
});

$('div.menu ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  closeMenu();
});


function openMenu() {
  (document.getElementById("see").setAttribute("style", "display: block;"));
  $('div.menu-bg').addClass('animate');

  $('div.burger').addClass('open');
  $('div.x, div.z').addClass('collapse');

  setTimeout(function () {
    $('div.y').hide();
    $('div.x').addClass('rotate30');
    $('div.z').addClass('rotate150');
  }, 70);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('div.x').addClass('rotate45');
    $('div.z').addClass('rotate135');
  }, 120);
}

function closeMenu() {

  $('.menu li').removeClass('animate');
  (document.getElementById("see").setAttribute("style", "display: none;"));
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('div.burger').removeClass('open');
    $('div.x').removeClass('rotate45').addClass('rotate30');
    $('div.z').removeClass('rotate135').addClass('rotate150');
    $('div.menu-bg').removeClass('animate');

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('div.x').removeClass('rotate30');
      $('div.z').removeClass('rotate150');
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('div.y').show();
      $('div.x, div.z').removeClass('collapse');
    }, 70);
  }, 100);

}
```

```css
body {
 background: blue;
 }
.nav {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 15px center;
  background-size: auto 40px;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.nav img {
  float: left;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.menu {
  display: none;
}
div.burger {
  height: 30px; 
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px; 
  left: 21px;
}
  div.x,
  div.y,
  div.z {
    position: absolute; margin: auto;
    top: 0px; bottom: 0px;  
    background: #fff;
    border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
            transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  }  
  div.x, div.y, div.z { height: 3px; width: 26px; }
  div.y {top: 18px;}
  div.z {top: 37px;}
  div.collapse {
    top: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
            transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  }
   
  
  div.rotate30 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); 
      transform: rotate(30deg); 
    -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
            transition: all 50ms ease-out;     
  }
  div.rotate150 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg); 
      transform: rotate(150deg); 
    -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
            transition: all 50ms ease-out;     
  }
  
  div.rotate45 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
      transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;     
  }
  div.rotate135 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
      transform: rotate(135deg); 
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;     
  }
div.menu-bg { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:#203d63;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
       -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
          transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000); 
}
div.menu-bg.animate{
  opacity:0.9;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -moz-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -ms-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
       -o-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
          transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);     
  
}
ul.menu {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
ul.menu li {
  width:300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.menu span {
  text-align: right;
}
ul.menu li a {
  background-color: white;
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0); 
  opacity: 0.75;
}
section > div {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
  <div class="menu-bg"></div>
  <ul class="menu" id="see">
    <li class="home">
      <a href="#"><img src="" alt="img" height="40px" /><span>Главная</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="gallery">
      <a href="#"><img src="" alt="img" height="40px" /><span>Галерея</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="z"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove following line from `openMenu` function.

```
$('div.menu-bg').addClass('animate');
```

Please look at the updated `openMenu` function.

```js
if( 'ontouchstart' in window ){ var click = 'touchstart'; }
  else { var click = 'click'; }


  $('div.burger').on(click, function(){
      if( !$(this).hasClass('open') ){ openMenu(); } 
      else { closeMenu(); }
    });

  $('div.menu ul li a').on(click, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    closeMenu();
  });


  function openMenu(){
        (document.getElementById("see").setAttribute("style", "display: block;"));
        
    //Remove this line
    // $('div.menu-bg').addClass('animate');     

    $('div.burger').addClass('open'); 
    $('div.x, div.z').addClass('collapse');
    
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $('div.y').hide(); 
      $('div.x').addClass('rotate30'); 
      $('div.z').addClass('rotate150'); 
    }, 70);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('div.x').addClass('rotate45'); 
      $('div.z').addClass('rotate135');  
    }, 120);  
  }
  
  function closeMenu(){

        $('.menu li').removeClass('animate');
        (document.getElementById("see").setAttribute("style", "display: none;"));
    setTimeout(function(){    
      $('div.burger').removeClass('open'); 
      $('div.x').removeClass('rotate45').addClass('rotate30'); 
      $('div.z').removeClass('rotate135').addClass('rotate150');    
      $('div.menu-bg').removeClass('animate');   
      
      setTimeout(function(){    
        $('div.x').removeClass('rotate30'); 
        $('div.z').removeClass('rotate150');    
      }, 50);
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('div.y').show(); 
        $('div.x, div.z').removeClass('collapse');
      }, 70);
    }, 100);             
    
  }
```

```css
body {
 background: blue;
 }
.nav {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 15px center;
  background-size: auto 40px;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.nav img {
  float: left;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.menu {
  display: none;
}
div.burger {
  height: 30px; 
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px; 
  left: 21px;
}
  div.x,
  div.y,
  div.z {
    position: absolute; margin: auto;
    top: 0px; bottom: 0px;  
    background: #fff;
    border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
            transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  }  
  div.x, div.y, div.z { height: 3px; width: 26px; }
  div.y {top: 18px;}
  div.z {top: 37px;}
  div.collapse {
    top: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
            transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  }
   
  
  div.rotate30 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); 
      transform: rotate(30deg); 
    -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
            transition: all 50ms ease-out;     
  }
  div.rotate150 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg); 
      transform: rotate(150deg); 
    -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
            transition: all 50ms ease-out;     
  }
  
  div.rotate45 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
      transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;     
  }
  div.rotate135 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
      transform: rotate(135deg); 
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;     
  }
div.menu-bg { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:#203d63;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
       -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
          transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000); 
}
div.menu-bg.animate{
  opacity:0.9;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -moz-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -ms-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
       -o-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
          transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);     
  
}
ul.menu {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
ul.menu li {
  width:300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.menu span {
  text-align: right;
}
ul.menu li a {
  background-color: white;
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0); 
  opacity: 0.75;
}
section > div {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-bg"></div>
<ul class="menu" id="see">  
<li class="home"><a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="img" height="40px"><span>Главная</span></a></li>
<li class="gallery"><a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="img" height="40px"><span>Галерея</span></a></li>
</ul>               
<div class="burger">
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="y"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
</div> 
</nav>
```

Comment: @Alexandra Glad to help. If this solved your issue you can mark it as the right answer.